# Elasticseaarch java.util.Objects.requireNonNull in type field in DocWriteResponse

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have problem with parsing response because I have null value in "type" field in DocWriteResponse which is required. I don't understand it because this type is deprecated but still required.
Have yuo idea how can I avoid this problem?

Code:

```
java.io.IOException: Unable to parse response body for Response{requestLine=POST /_bulk?timeout=1m HTTP/1.1, host=xxx, response=HTTP/1.1 200 OK} 
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient$1.onSuccess(RestHighLevelClient.java:1665) [elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.6.1.jar:7.6.1] 
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$FailureTrackingResponseListener.onSuccess(RestClient.java:590) [elasticsearch-rest-client-7.6.1.jar:7.6.1] 
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$1.completed(RestClient.java:333) [elasticsearch-rest-client-7.6.1.jar:7.6.1] 
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$1.completed(RestClient.java:327) [elasticsearch-rest-client-7.6.1.jar:7.6.1] 
at org.apache.http.concurrent.BasicFuture.completed(BasicFuture.java:122) [httpcore-4.4.14.jar!/:4.4.14] 
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.responseCompleted(DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.java:181) [httpasyncclient-4.1.4.jar!/:4.1.4] 
at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.processResponse(HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.java:448) [httpcore-nio-4.4.14.jar!/:4.4.14] 
at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.inputReady(HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.java:338) [httpcore-nio-4.4.14.jar!/:4.4.14] 
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultNHttpClientConnection.consumeInput(DefaultNHttpClientConnection.java:265) [httpcore-nio-4.4.14.jar!/:4.4.14] 
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:81) [httpasyncclient-4.1.4.jar!/:4.1.4] 
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:39) [httpasyncclient-4.1.4.jar!/:4.1.4] 
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:121) [httpcore-nio-4.4.14.jar!/:4.4.14] 
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:162) [httpcore-nio-4.4.14.jar!/:4.4.14] 
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:337) [httpcore-nio-4.4.14.jar!/:4.4.14] 
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:315) [httpcore-nio-4.4.14.jar!/:4.4.14] 
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:276) [httpcore-nio-4.4.14.jar!/:4.4.14] 
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104) [httpcore-nio-4.4.14.jar!/:4.4.14] 
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:591) [httpcore-nio-4.4.14.jar!/:4.4.14] 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) [?:?] Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:208) ~[?:?] 
at org.elasticsearch.action.DocWriteResponse.<init>(DocWriteResponse.java:127) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.1.jar:7.6.1] 
at org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexResponse.<init>(IndexResponse.java:50) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.1.jar:7.6.1] 
at org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexResponse.<init>(IndexResponse.java:39) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.1.jar:7.6.1] 
at org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexResponse$Builder.build(IndexResponse.java:103) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.1.jar:7.6.1] 
at org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexResponse$Builder.build(IndexResponse.java:100) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.1.jar:7.6.1] 
at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkItemResponse.fromXContent(BulkItemResponse.java:158) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.1.jar:7.6.1] 
at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkResponse.fromXContent(BulkResponse.java:196) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.1.jar:7.6.1] 
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.parseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:1793) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.6.1.jar:7.6.1] 
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.lambda$performRequestAsyncAndParseEntity$10(RestHighLevelClient.java:1581) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.6.1.jar:7.6.1] 
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient$1.onSuccess(RestHighLevelClient.java:1663) [elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.6.1.jar:7.6.1] ... 18 more
```

One solution is upgrade api elasticsearch in my project to 8.0.0 version, but my elasticsearch on server is still 7.X, so I want to be compatibile with server version.
Have you any ideas?